# return rows in a html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with returning rows from html table.
 can someone guide me how to do it ? 
I use tbody tag in my table too.
I have no clue what am I doing wrong ....

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="DeleteRow()"> delete </button>
<table id="myTable" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="header">
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>            
                        </tr>              
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
                            <td> 1 </td>            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
                            <td> 2 </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<script>
function DeleteRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable") ; //table itself
            var tableBody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody") ; //body of table
            var rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr") ; //rows in table-body
            document.write(rows.length) ; //wont work 
        }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I know document.write is not a good way to print things but I just want to test it ,,, the problem is "document.write(rows.length)" wont return anything

Comment: LOOK AT YOUR CONSOLE.

Comment: try to add plunker/fiddler link, so that community can quickly solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are referencing getElementsByTagName on an HTML Collection

```
var tableBody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody") <-- HTML COllection
var rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr") ; <--html collection does not have getEl....
```

you need to reference an index to use the method

```
var rows = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the information into something to he displayed you could use $('#message').html(rows.length); where message would be the I'd of the div you want the information in

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementsByTagName()` returns a HTMLCollection (which is like an array :)

```js
function DeleteRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable") ; //table itself
            var tableBody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody") ; //body of table
            var rows = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName("tr") ; //rows in table-body
            document.write(rows.length) ; //wont work 
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="DeleteRow()"> delete </button>
<table id="myTable" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="header">
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>            
                        </tr>              
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
                            <td> 1 </td>            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
                            <td> 2 </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<script>

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not an array